# a better clojure idiom for mapping a seq of fns to an input

Tags: clojure

I have been coming across this pattern a lot in my code `(map #(% a) fns)` where a is a variable say a string and fns is a seq of fns like `[count #(split ",")]`. Is there a more concise way to express this pattern ?

Answer (score 3):

More concise? Probably not. Better idiom? Depends. `juxt` will take any number of fns as arguments and provide a function that is their juxtaposition. So, you could use it in place of your `map` like so

```
(def a "foo,bar,baz")

(map #(% a) [count #(split % #",")])
;=> (11 ["foo" "bar" "baz"])

((juxt count #(split % #",")) a)
;=> [11 ["foo" "bar" "baz"]]
```

On one hand, you have a lazy sequence of applications, on the other you have functional composition. Which is better depends on the need.

Comment: Just for completeness, in your case it would be `((apply juxt fns) a)`, which is what I would consider the most idiomatic in the case that you are not requiring a lazy sequence.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way to express it: `(for [f fns] (f a))`

Added only for completeness, it's as good as the `map`-based expression, unless you like `for` more than anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is already concise. But if you want to create an abstraction which represent a `function collection` and is also callable, you can try something like this:

```
(defmacro function-coll [param-count]
  (let [params (repeatedly param-count gensym)
        name (symbol (str "Functions-" param-count))]
    `(deftype ~name [fns#]
       clojure.lang.IFn
       (invoke [_ ~@params] (map #(% ~@params) fns#)))))


(function-coll 1)
(def one-fns (->Functions-1 [inc dec]))
(one-fns 10)

(function-coll 2)
(def two-fns (->Functions-2 [str vector]))
(two-fns :hello :world)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the thrush operators are called for here.

```
user=> (-> "a b c d" 
       .toUpperCase 
       (.replace "A" "X") 
       (.split " ") 
       first)
"X"
```

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E%3E

Comment: Oops, I missed the requirement for a seq of fns.